# Setting a variable once for each time rspec is run

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am writing a Ruby gem that accesses the features of a web based API. I need to set up an object which will be initialized and log into the API just once for each time the tests are run. `before(:all)` is still excessive because it will run once for every describe block, and what I want is something that universally sets up once for all of the test files.

*UPDATE*

Just as a follow up, to make the object I was using available in the tests, I had to add a setting to the rspec config like this

```
config.add_setting :client
config.before(:suite) do
  RSpec.configuration.client = TDAmeritradeApi::Client.new
  RSpec.configuration.client.login
end
```

And then in the describe blocks I do this:

```
let(:client) { RSpec.configuration.client }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `before(:suite)` and you can use it in the config section of your `spec_helper.rb`.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    # API login
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `before(:suite)` to run a block of code before any example groups are run. This should be declared in `RSpec.configure`

Source: http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Hooks